# I cant install any Nodejs packages

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, truffle

I was trying to install Truffle using the below command
`npm install -g truffle`

but I am getting this error

```
npm ERR! code HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW
npm ERR! errno HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.orgregistry.npmjs.org/ failed, reason: Parse Error: Header overflow

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Victor\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-10-31T10_14_04_662Z-debug-0.log
```

I tried to install other packages but I was getting the same error

Comment: Are you using Zscaler by any chance? Found [this](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/16995)

Comment: I dont think so

Comment: What version of node and npm are you using?

Comment: I tried using 2 versions: node js 20.9.0 and 18.6.0